# scipy minimize build model

Tags: python, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, scipy-optimize

I have a nonlinear problem that I am trying to solve with scipy minimize.

The thing is that for now I am trying to pose the first constraint (with only that one the problem is linear) and I am having problems.

To contextualize, the case is that I have two stores and a total demand in units of a certain product for 52 weeks (1 year).

What is required is to be able to distribute that total annual demand across the two stores and determine how much demand each can supply.

the first 52 variables correspond to store 1 and the remaining 52 to store 2. What I am looking for is to minimize the demand that cannot be supplied in the year.

Objective Function: For each week Sum(Total demand - demand served by store 1 - demand served by store 2 )

My first restrictions are that the demand that can be served by store 1 and store 2 per week must be less than or equal to the available demand.

for now this is mi code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import minimize

weeks = 52
stores = 2

#FO
def objetivo(x,week,total):
    total_sum = 0
    
    for i in range(week):
        total_sum = total_sum + total[i] - x[i] - x[i+52]
        
    return total_sum

# bounds
b = (0.0, None)
limites = (b*(weeks*stores))

#Init values
x0 = [10000 for i in range(weeks*stores)]

#Constrains
restricciones = []
for i in range(semanas):
    restricciones.append({'type':'ineq', 'fun':lambda x:-x[i]-x[i+weeks]+uc['total'].values[i]})

solucion = minimize(objetivo,x0,method='SLSQP',args = (semanas,uc['total'].values),bounds=limites,constraints=restricciones)
```

uc['total'] is the weekly demand of the year.

By helping me understand what I am doing wrong I could continue with the other restrictions, thank you for your time.

With the actual code I get this error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for how to create a minimal reproducible example. Your code did not run.
2. Try

   ```
   # bounds
   b = (0.0, None)
   limites = [b]*(weeks*stores)
   ```

   (untested, code did not run).